# What are some of good text-based web editors/processors out there?

Tags: word-processor

I'm looking for a web-based text editor where a user can "track changes" and edit small portions of text that I can put on a commercial website that its users can use. The user should be able to highlight portions of the text, change the color, strike-through, etc. I'm wondering if there is a slick example out there.

It would go something like this: User 1 enters some text in the processor/editor. User 2 corrects it for them. Both users would see the changes and edits.

Answer (score 0):

Google docs supports all of that,  plus document sharing and collaboration work really well too.   If that doesn't do what you need, let me know what it misses/does wrong and there are a few other options!

http://aloha-editor.org/ looks promising!  You'll obviously need to handle the back-end to get the right users involved,  the docs on their look good.

http://aloha-editor.org/howto-store-data-with-aloha-editor-ajax.php

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually looking for one that I can put on a commercial website that its users can use. It would go something like this: User 1 enters some text in the processor/editor. User 2 corrects it for them. Both users would see the changes and edits.

Comment: That definitely looks really promising. Thank you!